A question about regularity of Schrodinger operator
I'm reading an article on Schrodinger operators. Consider the Schrodinger operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n), H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta+V$, where $V$ is real potential. The potential lies in a wide class. (For simplicity, we may first consider $V$ is continuous and bounded below.)
The author used the following property without explaining: suppose $z\notin Spec(H)$, then $\nabla(H-z)^{-1}\nabla$ is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and I'm confused with this.
Clearly $(H-z)^{-1}$ is bounded on $L^2$. But it seems that $(H-z)^{-1}$ maps $L^2$ to $H^2$. If $V$ is constant, this can be seen through Fourier transform. But for general $V$, I have no idea to prove it. And I'm not familiar with elliptic operator theory on unbounded domain.
So, how does the operator $(H-z)^{-1}$ improve the regularity?
